# how to install bottle package in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Facing problem while installing bottle package to python 2.7
I am using windows 7 system
which having python 2.7 & 3.4. 
'PY' command is for python 2.7 & 'PYTHON' command is for python 3.4

Now how to install bottle package in python 2.7

```
C:> py 
import bottle
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bottle
```

I installed for python 3.4 using **easy_install -U bottle** command.
 
It's working fine for python 3.4

```
C:>python
import bottle
```

I am facing problem how to install bottle packages in python 2.7

This is how my python 3.4 directory looks

```
C:\Python34>dir
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is 9CA3-A130
 Directory of C:\Python34<br />

 12/08/2014  09:49 PM    <DIR>          .
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM    <DIR>          ..
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM             1,024 add2virtualenv.bat
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM                83 cd-.bat
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM               644 cdproject.bat
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM               368 cdsitepackages.bat
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM               350 cdvirtualenv.bat
 09/28/2014  05:35 PM    <DIR>          distribution
 09/28/2014  01:28 AM    <DIR>          DLLs
 09/28/2014  01:28 AM    <DIR>          Doc
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM               421 folder_delete.bat
 09/28/2014  01:28 AM    <DIR>          include
 01/12/2015  01:36 AM    <DIR>          Lib
 09/28/2014  01:28 AM    <DIR>          libs
 05/18/2014  10:48 AM            31,073 LICENSE.txt
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM               997 lssitepackages.bat
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM               267 lsvirtualenv.bat
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM             1,947 mkvirtualenv.bat
 02/19/2011  01:40 AM           773,968 msvcr100.dll
 05/18/2014  10:33 AM           349,518 NEWS.txt
 05/18/2014  10:37 AM           102,400 py.exe
 05/18/2014  10:38 AM            27,136 python.exe
 05/18/2014  10:38 AM         2,734,592 python34.dll
 05/18/2014  10:39 AM            27,648 pythonw.exe
 05/18/2014  10:37 AM           102,912 pyw.exe
 05/04/2014  10:32 PM             6,942 README.txt
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM             1,000 rmvirtualenv.bat
 01/12/2015  01:35 AM    <DIR>          Scripts
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM               994 setprojectdir.bat
 09/28/2014  01:28 AM    <DIR>          tcl
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM               422 toggleglobalsitepackages.bat
 09/28/2014  01:28 AM    <DIR>          Tools
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM               183 whereis.bat
 12/08/2014  09:49 PM               936 workon.bat
          23 File(s)      4,165,825 bytes
          11 Dir(s)  30,791,503,872 bytes free
 C:\Python34>
```

Comment: how did you try installing for python2? You don't use the same packages for both python2 and 3

Comment: Is Py2 or Py3 in the path as main?

Comment: for myself I use pip for installing packages because I can choose python version for package installation .

Comment: Try: `mkvirtualenv -p \path\to\Python2\executable py2` Then: `whereis pip` (it should point to the virtualenv bin directory) Then: `pip install bottle`. To enable the virtualenv later: `workon py2`.

Comment: @JFSebastian Facing Error                           `C:\>mkvirtualenv -p "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe" C:\Users\kkotari\Desktop\mongo\python\vms\pyTwo`Then 
 `Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe`
 `New python executable in C:\Users\kkotari\Desktop\mongo\python\vms\pyTwo\Scripts\python.exe`
 `Installing setuptools.......................................done.
Installing pip...................done.`
 `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`
 `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going forward, I realized having 2.x and 3.x will give me problems on installing via pip or pip3 I need to be very specific and I can't have multiple 3.x version at same time.

While coming to Linux and Mac there is a feature to differentiate python environments using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), for Windows I have contributed recently called pyenv for windows [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win). Hope this might help.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend installing `pip` first and then running the command

```
pip install bottle
```

in your shell.

Answer (score 0):

First install **pip** in your system.
[How to Install Pip on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/)

Now, in new version of pip, you might need to enter

```
pip3 install bottle
```

Comment: It's was a compatibility issue in the olden days. Currently, I am using pyenv-win for managing multiple python environments.